# Getting all the properties of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

Does JavaScript have a way to get *all* the properties of an object, including the built-in ones? `for... in` skips built-in properties, which is usually what you want, but not in this case. I'm using Node.js if that matters, and it's for debugging purposes so it doesn't have to be elegant, fast or portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah it does, just go up through the prototype and get all properties

```
function getAllProperties(o) {
    var properties = [];
    while (o) {
        [].push.apply(properties, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o))
        o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o);
    }
    //remove duplicate properties
    properties = properties.filter(function(value, index) {
        return properties.indexOf(value) == index;
    })
    return properties;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the filter step?

Comment: Some properties may be repeated like toString or constructor so the filter step removes duplicates

Comment: Yes, but `getOwnPropertyNames()` should cover that, right?

Comment: No, `getOwnPropertyNames` only returns an array of "direct" properties of the object and _not_ those of its prototype (`Object.getOwnPropertyNames([])` just returns `['length']`). So to get all the properties of the object we have to go up the prototype chain and get their properties as well. And along the way some properties get overridden such as `toString` for `Array`s

Comment: Agreed.  But you already have code to go up the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for debug you could use this:

```
console.log(yourObject);
```

Simple and fast. Both in node and in browser. : )